# Simplifying a URL button

Tags: java, swing, exception, uri

I am trying to add a link to an "about" window in an application that will link to my Github. I sort of know the process, however, it seems to complicated for what it does, with all the error catching I have to put in. As I am certain the URI syntax is correct, is there any way to skip this catch? This variable stays final, and unless the syntax of resource location changes, it should be OK

Code:

```
        //TODO: Simplify?
        String gitLocation = "https://github.com/DanubeRS";
        try {
            final URI gitUri = new URI(gitLocation);

            //Add the github button action (link to site)
            githubButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    try {
                        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(gitUri.resolve(gitUri));  //Try to open URL
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        //URI unresolvable
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: doesn't look overly complicated to me.

Comment: Maybe I'm just paranoid? Maybe? * twitch *

Comment: `gitUri.resolve(gitUri)` isn't that just `gitUri`? (at least in this case with an absolute URI)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the convenience method [URI.create(String str)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#create%28java.lang.String%29), which wraps the `URISyntaxException` with an `IllegalArgumentException`.  From the JavaDoc:

> This method is provided for use in situations where it is known that
>   the given string is a legal URI, for example for URI constants
>   declared within in a program, and so it would be considered a
>   programming error for the string not to parse as such. The
>   constructors, which throw URISyntaxException directly, should be used
>   situations where a URI is being constructed from user input or from
>   some other source that may be prone to errors.

The `IOException` thrown from `Desktop.browse()` indicates that there's no default browser set up.  You should probably handle that gracefully by notifying the user.

Comment: A more appropriate call, and a tip thrown in as a bonus. Cheers.